# How can I get a list of friends who use my app?

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook-actionscript-api

So,

I'm trying Facebook.api("/me/friends?fields=installed",handleFunc); with no joy, I get a bad request error in Firebug.

However, I have no problem getting just a list of friends: Facebook.api("/me/friends", handleFriendsLoad);

I know there is a FQL way of doing this. But, why does the above not work for me? If FQL is the only way of doing this, what is the code needed?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

`/me/friends?fields=installed` **does not fetch friends using the app.**
But it fetches all your friends and an additional field `installed` with them.

FQL's way,
 
`SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND is_app_user = 1`

is the right way. 
If you are forced to use graph api, you can interate through all friends and check if a friend has field named `installed`.

A snippet of output from `/me/friends?fields=installed` is given below. It will help you to understand my answer.

```
{
  "id": "504726424"
},
{
  "id": "524806999"
},

{
  "installed": true,
  "id": "672755276"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using params as follow:

```
FacebookMobile.api("me/friends", handleFriendsList, {fields:"installed,name"});
```